# Can an Angular app call Api in a Springboot microservice through an eureka server?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I'm building an system in a microservice architecture, I have three Spring-boot microservice and a angular app, I know how to create a eureka service and register my springboot services to it but I could not find any sources on doing it in from my angular9 app, Which left me with some questions

1.Is there way to register angular9 app on a eureka server?

2.Do i need to register my angular app in order for me to make Rest API calls through the eureka service? i.e `http://myfirstservice/getservice`

3.If i register my springboot service to eureka server will they no longer be accessible by their default path? i.e `http://localhost:8081/getservice`

can some clarify these to me please? I'm really stuck. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why do you want to register your angular app to Eureka? Is your angular app shomehow expected to serve anything? Isn't your angular app a consumer to your microservices?

Comment: it is a consumer, but i'm under the impression that the angular app needs to register to the discovery server in order to consume it? am i wrong?

Comment: Instead of using a nginx proxy server, I think you can also create a gateway-service using Spring cloud Gateway, and then route the calls though it to the discovery server. In this way you do not need to register your angular app into eureka-server to call your backend services.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a reverse proxy server such as nginx.

Then your calls will take the form of http://yourdomain/getservice

And in your reverse proxy server, you must have a configuration that will accept requests and be proxied to your microservices, which, since you use eureka, may have addresses http://myfirstservice/getservice

For example:

```
http {
        ...    
        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name yourdomain;

                set $getservice myfirstservice:8081;
        }
    
        location ~ ^/getservice/(.*)$ {
                proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
                proxy_pass http://$getservice/getservice/$1$is_args$args;
        }
}
```

Where `myfirstservice` should be registered with `eureka`.

Comment: Since this is a work around, im guessing there's no direct way for angular to register with eureka? can you clarify the 3rd question i have mentioned?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a workaround, it's more of a standard path that most people use.
Regarding the 3rd question, if the microservice is deployed on the same server as the angular application, then http://localhost:8081/getservice must be available.
But for production, you must make static resources (html, js, css...) from your angular application, for example, with the 'npm run build' command, and nginx must distribute these static resources.

Comment: thankyou, this clarified my problem,basically it's not possible without using another service such as a nginx server am i right?

Comment: Yes, in general, one of the tasks that requires a web server, such as a nginx, is to receive requests from the client and give answers, for example, in the form of static files (html, js, css).